# Dúvida em como usar objeto date

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test2</title>
</head>
<script>
    var data = prompt("informe o numero do mês desejado: ");

    var mes =[
    "Janeiro",
    "Fevereiro",
    "Março",
    "Abril",
    "Maio",
    "Junho",
    "Julho",
    "Agosto",
    "Setembro",
    "Outubro",
    "Novembro",
    "Dezembro"];
    var mes= data.getMonth();

    console.log("Esse mes é "+mes);

</script>
</html>
```

No caso já consegui fazer a conversão de jogar um número e trazer um mês, porém quero fazer isso utilizando o objeto `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Você não está instanciando a variável para chamar o objeto `Date()`. Como o `Date()` não escreve os meses, e sim te retorna um valor numérico, por exemplo: O mês de Junho é representado pelo número 5.

Você terá que fazer uma estrutura de repetição, o mais recomendado para este caso, seria o `switch` segue o exemplo:

```js
var data = new Date();
var mes = data.getMonth();

switch (mes) {
    case 0:
        mes = 'Janeiro';
        break;
    case 1:
        mes = 'Fevereiro';
        break;
    case 2:
        mes = 'Março';
        break;
    case 3:
        mes = 'Abril';
        break;
    case 4:
        mes = 'Maio';
        break;
    case 5:
        mes = 'Junho';
        break;
    default:
        mes = 'Mês inválido';
}

alert('Nós estamos no mês de ' + mes);
```

Ou seja, como a variável `mes` está pegando o atual mês (Junho), que é representado pelo número 5, esta variável vai nos retornar o número 5. De acordo com a nossa estrutura de repetição, **caso** o retorno da variável `mes` seja 5, o novo valor da variável `mes` será "Junho".

Answer (score 1):

Use o método [`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) que retorna uma string com a representação da parte da data baseando-se no idioma.

```js
const data = new Date();                         //Pega a data do sistema.

const mes = data.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', {  //O retorno será em português do Brasil.
  month: 'long'                                 //Define que será retornado apenas o mês por extenso.
});

console.log("Esse mes é", mes);
```